# XAML (.NET MAUI) Entry with image to the left of it, with a frame that encloses both

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I am trying to achieve an entry with an image to the left of it. So far, I have been trying with frame but no luck. Since frame can only accept one element it won't work. Grid is an option but I want a continuous entry to say so. The image must be inside the entry.

Example of the search bar:

[Searchbox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLhSw.png)

Code that I have tried so far(but you will see that the two frames don't connect obviously and there is a very visible delimitation between them).

```
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="47" ColumnDefinitions="120, 200" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                             <Image Source="alert.png" HeightRequest="47" WidthRequest="47"/>
                         </Frame>
                        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Entry HeightRequest="47" WidthRequest="200" Placeholder="sdsada"/>                   
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
```

Comment: *"The image must be inside the entry"* That isn't possible. Do you mean *"the image must be inside the same frame as the entry"*? That would be a `HorizontalStackLayout`, containing Image and Entry.